# Change gray color of Navigation Drawer in android

Tags: android

I want to change Navigation Drawer gray color which is mention in image.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the shadow. You can use `drawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)` to remove the shadow.